# How does Cassandra handle the case of hash collision of the token function

Tags: cassandra

Considering three rows, (a, b), (a, f) and (c, e).

Sadly, under some flake partitioning algorithm, the partition key value `a` and `c` hashes to the same value.

In this case, how does Cassandra internally order the rows?

Will it be in:

```
(a,b)
(a,f)
(c,e)
```

or in

```
(a, b)
(c, e)
(a, f)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if the partition keys are different, there will be no chance of having same token (Hash Value).  Murmur3Partitioner will take care of uniqueness of token (hash).

```
row 1 (a,b) - a is partition key in this case. Hash will be calculated using a
row 2 (a,f) - a is partition key in this case. Hash will be calculated using a
row 3 (c,e) - c is partition key in this case. Hash will be calculated using c
```

Row number 1 and 2 are having same row kay (partition key), now this is collision. But cassandra has time stamp associated with every cell (a cell is smallest unit of storage in cassandra).Every cell has three properties Name, Value and Time Stamp. Cassandra use time stamp to merge these tow rows in to one row. The latest value will be persisted. From above example, for row kay a, value f will be persisted. Cassandra compaction process will take care of merging the rows.

Comment: The possible range of hash values is from -2^63 to +2^63-1, since it's a limited space, which means collision do have the chance to occur, though probably would never.

Comment: If collision happens, time stamp will be used to resolve the conflict. Data with latest timestamp will persist.

Comment: Yup. That's what I am interested in. So in the case if a, and c has a hash collision, so in the end, we will store one row from the original three rows in the question.

Comment: @Hacky - that assumes there are no other fields in the primary key except the partition key itself.